# how do i add a .resize function to the same .scroll function in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do i add a .resize function to the same .scroll function in jquery so that i can, when i scroll to a certain point on the page/at the bottom of the page it appears 2 divs on desktop and when on mobile when i scroll to a certain point/at the bottom of the page it appears one after another.

Since this is a very big website i'll paste only the js file if you want an idea go on the website and check out the js css and html under "Sources" in inspect element. i've placed in comments where i think the resize function would be

here's the website
https://54x1.github.io/AniBuy/pages/indexv2.html

here's the js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').fadeIn(1000);
  var oncedone1 = false;
  var oncedone2 = false;
  var oncedone3 = false;
  var oncedone1v1 = false;
  var oncedone2v1 = false;
  var oncedone3v1 = false;
  var oncedone4v1 = false;

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      /*$(window).resize(function() {*/
      /*desktop > 768px*/
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 1 && oncedone1 == false /*&& $(window).width() > 768*/ ) {
        $(".breakpoint").fadeIn(2500).css({
          "display": "grid"
        });
        $("#home-page-best-anime, .home-page-best-anime, #home-page-season-anime, .home-page-season-anime, #home-page-genre-anime, #home-page-action-anime, .home-page-action-anime").hide();
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 1 && oncedone2 == false) {
          $("#home-page-best-anime, .home-page-best-anime, #home-page-season-anime, .home-page-season-anime").fadeIn(2500).css({
            "display": "grid"
          });
          if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 1 && oncedone3 == false) {
            $("#home-page-genre-anime, #home-page-action-anime, .home-page-action-anime").fadeIn(2500).css({
              "display": "grid"
            });
            oncedone1 = true;
            oncedone2 = true;
            oncedone3 = true;
            //oncedone4 = true;
          }

        }
      }
      /*mobile / < 768px*/
      //if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100 && oncedone1v1 == false /*&& $(window).width() < 768*/) {
      //$(".breakpoint").fadeIn(2500).css({ "display": "grid" });
      //$("#home-page-best-anime, .home-page-best-anime, #home-page-season-anime, .home-page-season-anime, #home-page-genre-anime, #home-page-action-anime, .home-page-action-anime").hide();
      //if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100 && oncedone2v1 == false) {
      //  $("#home-page-best-anime, .home-page-best-anime").fadeIn(2500).css({ "display": "grid" });
      //if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100 && oncedone3v1 == false) {
      //  $("#home-page-season-anime, .home-page-season-anime").fadeIn(2500).css({ "display": "grid" });
      //if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100 && oncedone4v1 == false) {
      //  $("#home-page-genre-anime, #home-page-action-anime, .home-page-action-anime").fadeIn(2500).css({ "display": "grid" });
      //oncedone1v1 = true;
      //oncedone2v1 = true;
      //oncedone3v1 = true;
      //oncedone4v1 = true;
      //}
      //}
      // }
      //}
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .on() method to attach multiple event handlers to an element.

```
$(document).on('resize scroll', function (e) {
  alert(e.type);
});
```

Then use e.type to get the event type that triggered the function.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably not something you want to do with jQuery, but with css. It's quite easily solved with media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: i know you can use media queries but you can't fade in well scrolled to a certain point eg at the end of the page. though if u do know a way please share

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, then I misunderstood. I see you already found the correct solution, great! :)